# How to create XML file and HTM file in a folder with mule?

Tags: html, mule, mule-studio, xml

What I have done is extracted an XML file data and posted it in a ActiveMQ Queue. Now I have to retrieve the data from ActiveMQ queue and create a XML file in a folder? Same thing I have done with the HTM file. Extracted the HTML data and posted in queue. Now I have to create a HTM file in a folder. The problem is creating the XML file exactly it was. During posting request to queue I have converted XML and HTM file data to mule message in the following manner and then posted in queue-

'<'filename'>'XML_FILE_NAME'<'/filename'>'
'<'filedata'>'XML_FILE_DATA'<'/filedata'>'

'<'filename'>'HTM_FILE_NAME'<'/filename'>'
'<'filedata'>'HTM_FILE_DATA'<'/filedata'>'

For HTM file creation it gives error :-

**"[Fatal Error] :101:3: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "" 
ERROR 2015-06-17 10:08:03,476 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"**

Meta tag in HTM file should be created with this  tag exactly as it was.

How can these be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

When you're handling HTML files that can't validate as XML, try to transform them directly to strings or byte-arrays instead. Byte-arrays is preferable when putting it on a queue.

Once you've read the message from the queue, transform the byte-array to a string and log it's #[payload] to verify that you have the correct data so far.

Then you just have to use a file outbound-endpoint to store the data in a file. You can configure the directory it should write to directly in it's properties.

Comment: I have already converted the input but still same is occurring.